# How to add tags/slots to input field Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuetify-tabs

In Vue I have a basic input text field where the user will type something. I want to create removable slots based on what the user types. I have a button where the user can click "add slot" and then type what they want. Check picture 1. [image]

I want where when the user types in that field. Whatever they type become a slot like the second
picture.[image]

**I searched the docs and the Vue docs and their examples are too complicated. I want a simple example that shows the template div/input + autocomplete and the script to actually retrieve the values. **
Thank you for your help.

**I WANT THE UI TO BE LIKE THE SECOND PICTURE**

Answer (score 1):

You can set a click listener to that button, and upon clicking, take whatever user wrote, and store it in some data structure(probably array).
Then, loop through that array and create slots for each.
Set an onclick event for each slot, and remove index from array when clicking.

```js
<template>
<div>
    <input type="text border" v-model="text">
    <button @click="addSlot">Add Slot</button>
    <div>
       <div class="chip" v-for="(slot, idx) in slots" :key="idx">
           {{slot}}
           <i class="close material-icons" @click="removeSlot(idx)">close</i>
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
        text: '',
        slots: []
    }),
    methods: {
        addSlot() {
            this.slots.push(this.text)
            this.text = ''
        },
        removeSlot(idx) {
            this.slots.splice(idx, 1)
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sir, this is not what I am asking, I want to do this in Vue but show the UI like the pictures I provided. Please look at my question again. Thanks

Comment: I updated the answer. Added removeSlot method and button. I cant help you with css. What you refer as slot is called chips. if you are using any css library, search there for "chips". Or look at here: : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_contact_chips.asp

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I guess how do I v-chip my input?

Comment: i didn't understand your last question.

Comment: For example here is my input text field.   <label class="label">Slots</label>
             <input id="slots"
           v-model="txtInput"
            class="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Text input"
            />

Comment: How do I v-chip this?

Comment: How do I v-chip your example?